# Why is nsoperation working serially?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsoperation

I am using the following code for nsoperation.The problem is all three tasks run serially.What can I do to make the tasks run in parallel.I tried implementing the start and isconcurrent methods but it doesnt work.please help...
Given is my uaview controller class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    Store *S=[ [Store alloc] init];
    S.a=25;

    NSOperationQueue *someQueue = [NSOperationQueue currentQueue];

    someQueue.MaxConcurrentOperationCount = 3;

    NSInvocationOperation *invocationOp2 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]  initWithTarget:self
                                                                                 selector:@selector(ymain)
                                                                                   object:nil];

    NSInvocationOperation *invocationOp3 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]  initWithTarget:self
                                                                                 selector:@selector(ymain2)
                                                                                   object:nil];
    NSInvocationOperation *invocationOp4 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]  initWithTarget:self
                                                                                 selector:@selector(ymain3)
                                                                                   object:nil];


    [someQueue addOperation:invocationOp2];
    [someQueue addOperation:invocationOp3];
    [someQueue addOperation:invocationOp4];




}
-(void)ymain
{





    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i++) {
        NSLog(@"in the A main");    }
}
```

This is the other class which was subclassed

```
@interface A : NSOperation

@end

@implementation A

bool executing;
bool finished;
-(void)main
{

}
- (BOOL)isConcurrent
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)isReady
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to subclass `NSOperation` and override some methods there, and not in your `UIViewController`. Take a look at [Apple's programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html).

Comment: I have subclassed nsoperation in another classs

Comment: If you subclassed NSOperation, why are you not using the subclass?

Comment: What @HotLicks said. And frankly, you need to read up on some Objective-C programming before attempting anything like this.

Comment: how can I use the subclass in the nsinvocation operation?

Comment: I don't blame you for being confused -- the whole NSOperation thing is quite confusing, even if it weren't for the several documentation errors and the flip/flopping they do from one OS version to the next.  But if you're going to use that mechanism you need to spend some time studying it, not just copy a few lines from here and there and hope it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentQueue` is returning the main queue, which is a serial queue that executes on the main runloop. You should create your own `NSOperationQueue` to run the operations concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

`NSOperationQueue` manages the number of operations depending on various factors. This is an implementation detail which you cannot effect. You cannot force it to perform operations concurrently.

The only influence you can have is to set operation dependancy, which affects the order in which operations are performed serially (which isn't much use to you!)

Also `currentQueue` will return `nil` when it is called from outside of an `NSOperation`. If you use `mainQueue` then you'll get the queue which always runs on the main thread and only runs one operation at one. You need to create a new queue.